# Khinchin's weak law of large numbers: finite variance

Tags: random-variables, law-of-large-numbers

I have the following situation: suppose you have a sequence of i.i.d. random variables $\{X_i\}$ with mean $\mu$ and variance $1$.

I would like to use Khinchin's WLLN on it, but this requires that $\mathbb{E}(|X_i|)<\infty$. I clearly see that the finite variance implies $\mathbb{E}(X_i^2)=\mu^2+1<\infty$, but I cannot convince myself that this implies the expected value of absolute value of my r.v. is also finite.

Any ideas?

Comment: Cauchy-Schwarz!

Comment: Just $|t| < t^2 + 1$, so if $E(X^2)$ exists, $E(X)$ exists also :)

Comment: Finally understood how to leverage Cauchy-Schwarz here: $\mathbb{E}(|X_i|\cdot 1)^2 \leq \mathbb{E}(X_i^2)\mathbb {E}(1^2) = \mathbb E(X_i^2) < \infty$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $0<r<s$. Using [Hölder's inequality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Holder%27s_inequality#Probability_measure), we obtain that
$$
\operatorname E|X|^r\le\bigl(\operatorname E|X|^s\bigr)^{r/s}.
$$

So if a random variable $X$ has a finite absolute moment of order $s$, then it also has a finite absolute moment of any order less than $s$.

Comment: Great. Very confusing with names of these - I know it as Liapunov's inequality.

Comment: @adrug Yes, it is Lyapunov’s inequality. You can obtain it using Hölder's inequality or Jensen’s inequality.